# Error: will not let me enter my php dashboard with session

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing an activity for the school, when trying to login I must redirect to the "dashboard.php" but it does not redirect me and when I try to enter the URL to dashboard, it redirects me to "index" (it's the page I put in when there is no session) and if there is a session you should go to "dashboard"

login function

```
function login($username, $password)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ? || email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {

        if(isActivo($username)){

            $stmt->bind_result($id, $passwd);
            $stmt->fetch();

            $validaPassw = password_verify($password, $passwd);

            if($validaPassw){

                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_user'] = $id;

                header("Location: dashboard.php");
            } else {

                $errors = "La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta";
            }
        } else {
            $errors = 'El usuario no esta activo';
        }
    } else {
        $errors = "El nombre de usuario o correo electr&oacute;nico no existe";
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

login.php

```
require './config/conexion.php'; //here is the db connection file
require './config/funcs.php'; // here is the login function and another functions

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
  header("Location: dashboard.php");
}

$errors = array();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

  if(isNullLogin($username, $password)){
    $errors[] = "Debe llenar todos los campos";
  }
  $errors[] = login($username, $password);
}
```

dashboard.php

```
session_start();
require './config/conexion.php';
include './config/funcs.php';

if(!isset($_POST['id_user'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
} 

$idUser = $_SESSION['id_user'];

$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = '$idUser'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

and my index.php

```
require './config/conexion.php';
require './config/funcs.php';

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
  header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
```

Then, when I log in I should go to "dashboard" but it redirects me to "index" and I do not know how to look for this solution, I have already investigated a bit but I guess it is an error in the code or something like that.
I'm new to php.

Thank you

Comment: This line in your `dashboard.php` is potentially the problem: `if(!isset($_POST['id_user'])) {`.  In other places, you set `$_SESSION['id_user']` and here you are using `$_POST`.

Comment: Note: In all cases you should follow a call to `header("Location:...` with `die();` or `exit();` - otherwise the PHP script will keep on executing and will still output the remainder of the page, despite issuing a redirect header. This can leak supposedly-secure information to search engines, bots and other non-browser HTTP clients which may be trying to access your site.

Comment: I eliminated if(!isset($_POST['id_user'])) { and now works but now when a user not logged in tries to enter the dashboard, it lets it go, how could it be resolved?

Comment: You should replace if(!isset($_POST['id_user'])) { with : if(!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {

Comment: And also you cannot set the session in your login function before using session_start();

Comment: OMG! now all works normally, thank u so much, really thank you!

Comment: If you use prepared statements there is no need to call `real_escape_string` again. There is nothing to escape anymore. You still use simple concatenation for your other query, which makes it potentially susceptible to SQL injection. Prepared statements should be used as default by design, if you mix between the two you are bound to make a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need too use *session_start ()* before setting any session !
Second, in your login function, you set the *session* but in your dashboard you check for *POST*, you should replace :

```
if(!isset($_POST['id_user'])) {
 header('Location: index.php');
}
```

With :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
    exit(header('Location: index.php'));
}
```